# Ruby: implementing an extra condition in an elegant way

Tags: ruby

I'm automating some tests in Appium using ruby.
I'm writing code that looks somewhat like this

```
...
element_list #array filled with elements from a UI
element_list.each { |element| element.click if #certain condition is met 
}
...
```

I search the array `element_list` for an element and **click** it if a certain condition is met. 
Now lets say that the element is found, but I actually need to **scroll** down in order to **click** it.

I can't think of an elegant way of implementing that extra condition here.

Any ideas?

Comment: what about `select`?

Comment: Do you want to click all of them or just the first one?

Comment: @tadman just the first one

Comment: `find` or `detect` is probably a better way to get the element you need. What do you mean by scroll down? Scroll the visual page? Is there one? Is it not possible to just click on the element you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to click the first element that matches some criteria is to use the [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method:

```
to_click = element_list.find do |element|
  element.matches_criteria?
end

to_click&.click
```

The `find` method may return `nil` which is why the conditional navigation operator (`&.`) is required. This avoids trying to click `nil`.

The `matches_criteria?` method is just an example. `find` will return the first element for which the block yields a logically true value.

Comment: Also, `detect` is another name for `find` for this behavior.

Comment: @tadman thanks, `find` was exactly what I needed. Also didn't know about the `&.`, which I know now thanks to your answer. very cool!!